# Can't change vibration strength on Lineage OS

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-5, vibration, lineageos

I just installed Lineage OS 14.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S5 Plus. However, the vibration strength for - for example - pressing the "Recent Apps" or "Back" button and typing was pretty much the maximum.

When I go to settings I can't find a setting for changing the the vibration strength, when I search, however, I can find a setting for vibration strength, but when I click on it, I go to "Other sounds" and don't find that found result there...

So how can I change the vibration strength on Lineage OS 14.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a newer version of Lineage OS it may be worth updating to see if this was a known fault for your model.

[image]

Comment: I bought a new smart phone since my S5+ was doing odd and I had issues with Linease OS, like bluetooth connection with my car and IMAP syncing. But an update would probably be the only solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open ***Settings*** and use ***Search***. If there is a setting available it will take you straight there.

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**Open settings and use search**</sup>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I'm not a newb on Android and I know there's a searching functionality. Hence the reason why I asked it here. :)

Answer (score -4):

On the keyboard, rest your hand on the world sign and select Google keyboard.. that's all.. the vibrations will stop [image]